# Can my VPN provider see my browsing activities on SSL sites?

Tags: tls, web-browser, man-in-the-middle, vpn

I gather they can probably see everything if they want to on non-SSL sites but how about on SSL sites, can they do it?

Answer (score 1):

No, they can't, assuming you trust the certificate on the site.

However, your VPN provider can still monitor metadata that is not encrypted, such as DNS requests and IP addresses of hosts you communicate with. They could at least reveal on what domains you have possibly visited.

Comment: Regarding "domains you have possibly visited", are there ways to conceal those information?

Comment: You can't hide the IP addresses you are connecting to. If only one site is served from the address, it clearly reveals where you've visited. I'm not too familiar with DNS encryption etc. schemes, "How to prevent DNS request from being observed" is really another question.